# Are VMs in Azure Cloud deployed with the App?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, azure, webserver

Are VMs in Azure Cloud deployed with the App?
Basically, I'm trying to understand if VMs wait for code to be deployed to them, or the VM is deployed and then started.  Kind of like deploying a Web Server with the app instead of the reverse (deploying an app to a web server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure platform deploys and runs a bunch of VMs before hand to speed up the deployment process, then your app is deployed to those VMs.

The podcast with Mark Russinovich also points that out (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/se-podcast-25-mark-russinovich/). I do not recall the exact time, but I remember Mark mentioned that in the next year and a half, the Azure team is planning to improve the deployment time, then Joel Spolsky asked him why don't they predeploy a bunch of VMs and put them in standby mode to save on boot time, then Mark says that they're already doing this but it's more complicated to speed up the deployment than it looks like and that they're working on it.